# Как передать данные в представление через ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Нужно отобразить в представлении сумму за товар в нескольких валютах (USA, EUR) через запятую ($ 5, EUR 4,25) Курсовка храниться в классе

```
public class ExchangeRate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string _currencyCode { get; set; }
    public string _currencyName { get; set; }
    public double _currencyRate { get; set; } 
}
```

На основе которого создана таблица в базе данных, где и хранятся курсовки.

Пробовал вывести так

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var exchangeRate = _context.ExchangeRates.FirstOrDefault();
    ViewBag.Rate = exchangeRate._currencyRate;

    IEnumerable<Phone> phone = _context.Phones.OrderBy(p => p.Name);
    return View(phone);
}
```

в представлении

```
ViewBag.Rate
```

Не работает.

Пробовал так

```
$ @item.Price 
@(item.Price * item._priceRUB) // _priceRUB  это ссылка на таблицу где храниться значение
```

Выводит ($ 1,249 1,249) то есть он умножает на id , а нужно ($ 1,249 71,193) что бы умножал на значение хранящееся по этому id.

Класс Phone

```
public class Phone
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Телефон")] public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Цена")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public double Price { get; set; }


        public double _priceRUB { get; set; }
        public ExchangeRate ExchangeRUB { get; set; }


        public double _priceEUR { get; set; }
        public ExchangeRate ExchangeEUR { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Описание")] public string _description { get; set; }
        public string _redirectUrl { get; set; }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<PhoneOnStock> PhoneOnStocks { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `Не работает.` что это означает?

Comment: @tym32167 Выводит не то что должно! Выводит ($ 1,249 1,249) то есть он умножает на id , а нужно ($ 1,249 71,193) что бы умножал на значение.

Comment: Вам стоит добавить описание модели Phone чтобы уж точно не было неоднозначности. И я так понимаю, что у вас в таблице ExchangeRates хранится одно-единственное значение для обменного курса, которое вы не обновляете? Может вы хотите для каждого телефона подгрузить через .Include связанный обменный курс?

Comment: Так, у вас есть телефон с ценой Price. В какой валюте хранится это Price? В долларах? И в таблице ExchangeRate приведено значение для перевода долларов а) в RUR и б)  в EUR, так? Ну или не в долларах, но всегда в какой-то одной и той же валюте - причем именно для этой валюты создана таблица ExchangeRate , верно?

Comment: @A K Да цена в долларах. В ExchangeRate значение для перевода в RUB и EUR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему вы считаете, что Rate - это часть Phone, ведь вы её в ViewBag сложили.

Action оставляете как есть:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var exchangeRate = _context.ExchangeRates.FirstOrDefault();
    ViewBag.Rate = exchangeRate._currencyRate;

    IEnumerable<Phone> phones = _context.Phones.OrderBy(p => p.Name);
    return View(phones);
}
```

А View должно быть таким:

```
@model IEnumerable<Phone>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   @(item.Price * ViewBag.Rate) ,
}
```

Либо указывайте не `ViewBag.Rate` а `ViewBag["Rate"]` - это в общем-то тоже самое.

Вот и всё.

Ответ на обновлённый вопрос.

Если у вас в таблице цена телефона хранится в USD, а в таблице ExchangeRate две записи - одна для перевода в RUR, другая - для EUR, то складываем во вьюбаг сразу два значения:

```
public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Company { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

(Обратите внимание, что ExchangeEUR и ExchangeRUR не нужны на классе Phone)

Action:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var exchangeRateRur = _context.ExchangeRates.FirstOrDefault(x => x._currencyCode == "RUR");
    ViewBag.RateRur = exchangeRateRur._currencyRate;

    var exchangeRateEur = _context.ExchangeRates.FirstOrDefault(x => x._currencyCode == "EUR");
    ViewBag.RateEur = exchangeRateEur._currencyRate;

    IEnumerable<Phone> phones = _context.Phones.OrderBy(p => p.Name);
    return View(phones);
}
```

(поскольку мы работаем с SQL сервером, то можем использовать `==` а не `string.Equals` со строгим указанием культуры - главное понимать, почему так можно делать и когда)

Представление:

```
@model IEnumerable<Phone>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   @item.Price USD @(item.Price * ViewBag.RateRur) RUR @(item.Price * ViewBag.RateEur) EUR ,
}
```

Comment: @A K Работает Спасибо!

Comment: Да ладно? А я уже думал, что у вас в каждом телефоне лежит ExchangeRateId и нужно показывать как писать подгрузку связанных данных через `.Include()`

Comment: @A K У меня в таблице ExchangeRateId два наименования RUB и EUR так вот работает на одной валюте, а как сделать что бы выводил разный результат?  ` RUB @(item.Price * ViewBag.Rate)  EUR @(item.Price * ViewBag.Rate)` в представлении  по задумки нужно так ($ 1,249 RUB 71,193 EUR 99,92) а, выводит $ 1,249 RUB 71,193 EUR 71,193 , так что оказалось не совсем правильно работает!

Comment: @A K А, про погрузку не могли бы поподробней?

Comment: @EugeneTM Ага, всё-таки разные валюты! Как знал! )) Ну тогда редактируйте вопрос и вписывайте класс Phone

Comment: @A K ок сейчас отредактирую!

Comment: @A K Спасибо заранее! Жду! Не как не могу понять:(

Comment: @EugeneTM Добавил, но вообще про подгрузку я кажется зря сказал: `.Include()` понадобился бы, если бы у вас в Phone хранилось бы поле Price и Currency  - а у вас всё в одной валюте.

Comment: @A K А, почему два Price int и double?

Comment: @EugeneTM Потому что у меня под рукой нет студии, чтобы подсказать, что я ошибся ;) Убрал, это я наполовину написал свой код, а половину копипастил из вашего - и не заметил, что у вас уже было Price.

Comment: @A K Понятно! А, то я  запутался! Спасибо!

Comment: @A K Всё работает огромное спасибо!